# Are my Big-O justifications correct? Especially not sure about n^n

Tags: big-o

a) `f(n) = n^n + 6n^5 – 11` = O(n^n).
Justification: Any integer ≥ 7 would make n^n becomes dominant.

b) `f(n) = 3log_2n + 12n` = O(log n).
Justification: 3log_2n + 12n ≤ 15log_2n, for n ≥ 2.

c) `f(n) = 30 + 2n^4 – 20n^2 + n` = O(n^4).
Justification: 30 + 2n^4 – 20n^2 ≤ 12n^4, for n ≥ 1.

d) `f(n) = 7n^(5/7) +2n` = O(n^(5/7))
Justification: 7n^(5/7) +2n ≤ 9n^(5/7), for n ≥ 1.

Comment: I would compute b) as `(3*log_2(n)) + (12*n)`, so it's `O(n)`.

Comment: d) `n = 1000` -> `7n^(5/7) + 2n = 2972.6 > 1250.5 = 9n^(5/7)` -> your classification is wrong. Correct would be `O(n)`.

Comment: Generally, the way we derive `O()` expressions is by dropping all additive subexpressions that become irrelevantly small compared to other subexpressions that are present. And then by dropping any constant factors. I.e. a) `n^n + 6n^5 - 11`, 11 grows slower than `n^5` so drop it, `n^5` grows slower than `n^n` so drop it -> order is `O(n^n)`.

Comment: Likewise, b) `log(n)` grows slower than `n`, so drop the `3log_2n` term, kill the constant, and you get `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation is about growth, so your `n^n` justification about `a)` is correct. Remember to always focus on the highest degree term, because it will always grow faster than the others, as `n` increases.

So, while `a)` and `c` are correct, for `b)` I will say it's **O(n)** because linear complexity grows faster than logarithmic. For `d)` it's **O(n)** again, because `7n^(5/7)` is actually shrinking, so `12n` is growing faster.